# How to make operations between keys in Rule Chain

Tags: javascript, thingsboard

I used two aggregate stream nodes to sum per day some values. Now I want to make operations between the results of that nodes. I was trying with the new generated keys in a script node but it doesn't work because apparently the aggregate stream node results are sended in different times.

I will appreciate your help or suggestions!

This is how I'm trying to get the fetched values:

(I'm using the 'originator telemetry' in LAST mode)

```js
var newMsg = {};

newMsg.ratio_on_off = parseFloat(msg.tiempo_encendido_ms / (msg.tiempo_encendido_ms + msg.tiempo_apagado_ms));

return {msg: newMsg};
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the results of your aggregation to two telemetry/attribute keys. Then use "originator attributes" node to fetch the saved keys and do the calculation.

Comment: Hi! First of all thank's for your answer. I also tried with that method but always recieved null. I see just one value in the "test' window of the script node but the 'originator attributes' is fetching two keys. I will edit the question with the code I'm using in the script node.

Answer (score 0):

Since ThingsBoard Version 3.4.2 there is a new Rulenode called Math Function:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#math-function-node

With this node you can perform calculations with telemetries or attributes both from the message body/metadata or from stored datapoints. This may be an easier approach to solve your Problem:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wil be reading the documentation, that node seems to be very helpful.